# Spring security: concurrent queries with PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Spring REST web application and I am currently using Spring Security's `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` mechanism for user authentication.

I also need to make several requests to server from the same user concurrently, so it seems impossible to use `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` for that purpose, because the user token is updated every time after any authenticated user query.

**What would be the secure way of making several requests to server concurrently in my situation?**

I realize that it is an option to not update user token after every query, but store it unchangeable for some time, but this is not that secure, so I am looking for other options.

Comment: I commented out the updateToken-part.
It's not secure to never change the token.
You can allow two tokens for a certain period of time. The old and the new token.